# Rendering addressfield

Tags: 7, commerce, entities

In my Drupal 7 commerce website, I have my checkout page which will add my billing and shipping profiles. I need to just display my shipping address and billing address, instead of input fields. (Data fed from an ERP backend.)

So I've hidden al the input fields. Now I want to render the addresfield value and add it to my form just for display. But I seem to be unable to do so.

I  have the following code in my form alter:

```
  $handlers = array('address' => 'address');
  $context = array('mode' => 'render');
  $address_render_array = addressfield_generate($form['customer_profile_shipping']['customer_profile']['#value']->commerce_customer_address, 
                            $handlers, $context);
  dpm($address_render_array, 'render arr');
  dpm(drupal_render($address_render_array), 'rendered');
```

However drupal_render() returns an empty string and I do not understand why. I've tried to X-debug, and I saw strangely enough that #access vars where FALSE, but I'm not finding out why.

After which I want to display it in my form

Something like

```
$form['my-address'] = array('#markup' => $renderedaddress);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used

```
  $output = field_view_field('commerce_customer_profile', $form['customer_profile_shipping']['customer_profile']['#value'], 'commerce_customer_address');
  $form['customer_profile_shipping']['rendered_address'] = array(
    '#prefix' => '<div class="checkout-address">',
    '#markup' => render($output),
    '#suffix' => '</div>'
  );
```